# Shrinkwrapping has some pinching

Tags: modifiers

I'm shrink-wrapping and getting some pinching. My guide mesh has triple the amount of faces, so the detailed mesh can shrink-wrap on it. But where the holes are there is some obvious distortion. And some lines which appear where the bumper is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: subdivide the guide mesh

Comment: Thanks for that!

I was following an old tutorial, and I the layers panel isn't available in the tutorial, because its an outdated interface.

Comment: Is there anything called "Layers panel" in Blender? There is "View Layer" panel in the Properties editor, View Layer Properties tab, but what does it have to do with anything?

Comment: Yes my mistake its the view layers panel not layers panel, I got confused with photoshop. But some people do refer to it also as layers panel, because its heavily influenced by Photoshop which lots of Blender artist are using.

https://ibb.co/0MGySDM